# Connect to Samba share with no username/password

Tags: samba, password, user-accounts

I have just set up Samba on a CentOS 5 machine. It works OK, but I would like to configure it so that users can connect to Samba shares without the need to provide a user name and password. I have googled for a smb.conf reference but documentation seems to be quite scattered and not comprehensive. Can somebody explain how to achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using

```
[global]

security = share
```

in smb.conf.

This seems to be enough for passwordless access. The computers belong to the same workgroup, but I don't know if this is a mandatory requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Example of `smb.conf` for anonymous access:

```
#======================= Global Settings

[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   netbios name = Encre
   security = user
   hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24 127.0.0.1
   hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m
   max log size = 50
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY

#============================ Share Definitions

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   writable = yes

[other]
   comment = other!
   path = /home/otheruser/share
   force user = otheruser
   force group = otherusergroup
   read only = No
   guest ok = Yes

#============================
```

Comment: I hope the "porn" bit is optional!